# Django: Unable to render time changes on fullcalendar

Tags: django, python-3.x, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to render event changes to my fullcalendar but my timeslots keep disappearing when the page is refreshed.

I am successful when resizing or dragging events. As soon as I resize or drop my event changes in month view, my changes are saved in my database so my changes are reflected on my next refresh.

The problem is when I resize and drop on day view. My time changes are reflected on my database, but when I reload the page the timeslots reverts back to all day or 12am - 1am (depending on my allDay is true or false).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            weekNumbers: 'true',
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            showNonCurrentDates: true,

             dayClick: function(date) {
                new_date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');

                },

            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    id: "{{ i.id }}",
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    allDay: {{ i.all_day|lower }},
                    url: '/world'

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ],

                eventClick: function(event, element) {
                    event.title = "CLICKED!";

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);},


                eventDrop: function(event, element){
                    alert("Event is now " + event.start + " " + event.end)

                    var url = 'update_event';

                    var event_start = event.start;
                    var event_end = event.end;


                    var js_timestamp_start = event_start.getTime() / 1000;

                    if (event_end != null) {
                      var js_timestamp_end = event_end.getTime() / 1000;
                    }


                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                        'event_id': event.id,
                        'event_title': event.title,
                        'event_start': js_timestamp_start,
                        'event_end': js_timestamp_end,
                        'event_allDay': event.allDay},
                        success: function (data) {
                          alert("Success!")  },
                        error:
                            function(xhr){
                            alert(xhr.statusText)
                            return false;}
                    });

                },

                eventResize: function(event, element){
                    alert("Event is now " + event.start + " " + event.end)

                    var url = 'update_event';

                    var event_start = event.start;
                    var event_end = event.end;


                    var js_timestamp_start = event_start.getTime() / 1000;

                    if (event_end != null) {
                      var js_timestamp_end = event_end.getTime() / 1000;
                    }


                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                        'event_id': event.id,
                        'event_title': event.title,
                        'event_start': js_timestamp_start,
                        'event_end': js_timestamp_end,
                        'event_allDay': event.allDay},
                        success: function (data) {
                          alert("Success!")  },
                        error:
                            function(xhr){
                            alert(xhr.statusText)
                            return false;}
                    });
                },



            }); // end #calendar
    })
</script>
```

```py
def full_calendar(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()

    date_form = DateForm
    myr_form = MonthYearForm

    context = {
        "events": all_events,
        "get_event_types": get_event_types,
        "date_form" : date_form,
        "myr_form" : myr_form
    }

    return render(request, 'world/fullcalendar.html', context)


def update_event(request):

    event = None

    event_id = request.GET.get('event_id')
    event_start = request.GET.get('event_start')
    event_end = request.GET.get('event_end')
    event_title = request.GET.get('event_title')
    event_allDay = request.GET.get('event_allDay')
    event_allDay = event_allDay.capitalize()
    python_date_start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(event_start))

    if event_end is not None:
        python_date_end = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(event_end))
    else:
        python_date_end = python_date_start
        #From what I remember here, event end is null, it's because start and 
        #end is the same

    event = Events.objects.get(id=event_id)
    event.event_name = event_title
    event.start_date = python_date_start
    event.end_date = python_date_end

    event.all_day = event_allDay
    event.save()

    context = {"event": event}

    return render(request, 'world/update_event.html', context)
```

So if I have an event that is all day then changed it to 10am to 5pm, I expect my event to render as 10am to 5pm on refresh. Instead I got 12am - 1am (because my allDay is now false).

Oddly enough, changes I made is reflected on my db. I'm just not quite sure why my date changes are reflected on fullcalendar and my time changes are not.

Comment: Hi sorry, I think I found out the problem. It seems that I forgot to add the time part on my template. Format should be something like the code below and everything should be working.

'{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }} {{ i.start_date|time:"H:i:s" }}'

Comment: If you found the solution, that's great. But please add it to the Answers section below, so it's clear for everyone to see. You are allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I forgot to add the time part on my template. Format should be something like the code below and everything should be working. '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }} {{ i.start_date|time:"H:i:s" }}